# Insert tablecell when CoreData object has been added

Tags: iphone, core-data

Does anyone have some tips as to how to insert tablecells when CoreData objects have been added? What possibilities does coredata have to notify the tableView? Or should the tableView monitor CoreData? Will I get into trouble when doing a reloadData?
I am looking for a/the way to do this. I can probably figure the code out from there.

Comment: Thnx. I had no idea that I had to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the notifications from NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification

Answer (score 1):

That's what [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is for. Read the documentation for that class, it basically contains a full complement of code you need to implement.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and have many tableView with coredata as the source, but what I want to achieve now is have a UITableView on screen, and when in the background an entry is made into CoreData, I want to insert a tableCell (Without doing a reloadData).

Comment: Found something which looks like it can provide what I want: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification